# Overwrite Object Property with Another Object

Tags: vba, object, properties, mutators

I am working in VBA, and I need to set the `.Interior` property of a `Range` object, to the value of its own `.DisplayFormat.Interior`.  More generally, I want to paste the formatted *appearance* of copied cells, without pasting the conditional formatting rules that contributed (alongside any manual formatting) to that appearance.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to mutate an objective property like `.Interior`.

---

More generally: let `x` and `y` be two objects, each with the objective property `my_obj` of the same class `obj`; where `obj` has *n* scalar properties {`scal_1`, `scal_2`, ..., `scal_n`}.  I want to mutate `x.my_obj` such that it is identical to `y.my_obj`.

Obviously, this can be done "manually" by

```
x.my_obj.scal_1 = y.my_obj.scal_1 
x.my_obj.scal_2 = y.my_obj.scal_2
'       ⋮        ⋮         ⋮
x.my_obj.scal_n = y.my_obj.scal_n
```

but this manual approach is obviously **untenable** for objects of **arbitrary structure**.  Problems would especially arise for self-referential objects like `Application`, which have properties of their own class: `Application.Application`.

I had considered a recursive algorithm that iterates over an object's properties, and either performs normal assignment on scalar properties or recurses on objective properties. However, this would run forever (until crashing) on self-referential objects. To top it off, I can't even *find* a way to iterate over the properties of an arbitrary VBA object.

---

**Is there ultimately any way to implement the following psuedocode in VBA?**  Unfortunately, this code seems to be invalid for anything but scalar assignments.

```
' General case.
x.my_obj = y.my_obj

' Use case.
MyRange.Interior = MyRange.DisplayFormat.Interior
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a `clone()` method, and only 2 (hidden) objects in the _stdole_ library seem to have one - the closest native equivalent are the various `Copy` methods, e.g. copying the format (which encapsulates several properties) for a `Range` object

Comment: Oh dear, I worried that deep cloning was inevitable...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the rationale for wanting to clone, i.e. most objects have a host of properties, but a lot of the time many of them are never explicitly assigned a value (e.g. the ID property of a Range object) ?

Comment: My goal is to create a VBA macro, which is a specialized form of pasting.  Let `My_Range` be a `Range` copied to the clipboard, in which at least some formatting is generated by conditional formatting rules.  I want to paste `My_Range` as if all its formatting had been static: that is, I want to paste the **appearance** (the `.DisplayFormat`) without pasting the rules themselves.

Comment: @SpectralInstance Something like what is described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/paste-formatting-without-conditional-formatting/c8dd0276-076a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) or [here](https://professor-excel.com/how-to-remove-conditional-formatting-in-excel-but-keep-the-colors#Method_1_Remove_the_rules_but_keep_the_background_colors_with_a_VBA_macro), only instead of modifying the original range, I would be pasting the result of that modification.

Comment: Unless you investigated `winapi` programming, with a view to manipulating the clipboard contents, I don't know how you'd do this; using value assignment rather than the clipboard is one of the standard strategies for improving VBA running times so, unless you have particularly elaborate conditional formatting, your existing approach may actually be the most efficient.

Comment: @SpectralInstance I have indeed attempted a sub for value assignment, but it's not working as expected.  I try assigning the value of every `MyRange.DisplayFormat.*` to that of every matching `MyRange.*`, and only afterward erase conditional rules via `MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete`; but all this achieves is to wipe _all_ formatting.  Should I append this code to the question?